# How is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ at $x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a function:
$$\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
and the example says that: $\text{sinc}(0) = 1$, How is it true?

I know that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, But the graph of the function $\text{sinc}(x)$ shows that it's continuous at $x = 0$ and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: what is $sinc(x)$?

Comment: $\sin x \approx x \quad \forall x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Sorry for this, I edited the question.

Comment: @Autolatry, you meant the constraint $x \simeq 0 $

Comment: @imranfat: it's the *cardinal sine*, one of the special functions.

Comment: @Fraouk Sabry: I can't see why there  is a problem

Comment: @Bernard O, I see..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an elementary book, they should define $\mathrm{sinc}$ like this
$$
\mathrm{sinc}\; x = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{x}\qquad x \ne 0
\\
1\qquad x=0
\end{cases}
$$
and then immediately prove that it is continuous at $0$.

In a slightly more advanced book, they will just say
$$
\mathrm{sinc}\;x = \frac{\sin x}{x}
$$
and the reader will understand that removable singularities should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\operatorname{sinc}$ is defined as
$$
\operatorname{sinc}\colon x\in\mathbb{R} \mapsto \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{x} & \text{ if } x\neq 0\\
1 & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
(note that you cannot write $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for the case $x=0$). It *is* continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, because for $x\neq 0$ $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 1 = \operatorname{sinc}(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The exact definition of $sinc$ function is
$$
sinc(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x)}x, & \text{iff $x\neq0$}\\
1, & \text{iff $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect it to go to $\infty?$  In such cases L' Hospital's Rule can be  used to find the proper limit. The graph of the function $\text{sinc}(x)$ shows that it is continuous at $x = 0$ and that is why it makes sense.